# CURSOR with JOIN

Tags: sql

I'm having problems with `JOIN` with `cursor`s

```
DECLARE CURSOR c_cursor1 FOR
    SELECT empid from emptable;

For cur_row as c_cursor1() Do 
    SELECT salary into v_salary
    FROM table as A 
    INNER JOIN table as B
        ON (B.no ='123' AND A."ID"=cur_row.empID);
```

I get an error saying:

> cur_row.empid is not a valid table name...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your RDBMs?

Comment: why would you use cursor?

Comment: Can you add more on what you are trying to accomplish here? If just insert data, maybe INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE SELECT... would be enough, I don't see the need for cursor

Comment: Are you sure you want double quotes on "ID" in the last line A."ID"?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, that code (attemtp) is product specific.

Comment: Hi All, Sorry I'm using the HANA DB .. I have other code underneath but i'm stuck here ..        But if i pass the cur_row.empID into a variable and use that variable in the join it works fine for ex                                                                   
 DECLARE CURSOR c_cursor1 FOR
    SELECT empid from emptable;

For cur_row as c_cursor1() Do 
v_tempid = cur_row.empid;                                                               SELECT salary into v_salary
    FROM table as A 
    INNER JOIN table as B
        ON (B.no ='123' AND A."ID"= :v_tempid);

Comment: Any suggestions